# nodemon doesn't watch while started through npm script on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I try to run nodemon through npm script on Windows. At first i run script string in command prompt.
`./node_modules/.bin/nodemon -e ts --watch 'src/' --exec "npm run compile-component && node dist/index.js"`
It works without any problem. I change files in folder and nodemon watch it and restart server. But when i try to run it with npm, nodemon started. You can see log when i started script below.

```
PS D:\Projects\my-project> npm run dev

> my-project@1.0.0 dev D:\Projects\my-project
> nodemon -e ts --watch 'src/' --exec "npm run compile-component && node dist/index.js"

[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): 'src\'
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts
[nodemon] starting `npm run compile-component && node dist/index.js`

> my-project@1.0.0 compile-component D:\Projects\my-project
> tsc -p tsconfig.json

App is listening on port 3000
```

But when i change files, nodemon doesn't react on it.
I don't understand why it happened.
How i can resolve this problem?
`package.json` file presented below.

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile-component": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon -e ts --watch 'src/' --exec \"npm run compile-component && node dist/index.js\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: i don't understand, why it should ends, when i run same command in powershell myself, it works

Comment: do you know to get around this problem?

Comment: You don't need the -p tsconfig.json, it's just tsc this case